# Быстрый перезапуск окна PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qlabel

Есть генерируемые лэйблы на основе списка из файла, с которыми можно производить различные действия. Для примера я накидал разворачивание в обратном порядке и удаление.

После того, как в файл внесены изменения мне нужно перезапустить окно, чтобы были видны изменения. Делать перезапуск через `os` - слишком долго по времени. Я решил сделать через `self.close()` \ `self.__init__()`. Что для моей программы сработало, но для кода, который я накидал, чтобы спросить, насколько корректен этот метод - не работает. Хотя `print(2)` перед закрытием выполняется исправно.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()

        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.restart_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Reverse')

        self.restart_button.clicked.connect(self.reverse_foo)

        with open('path.txt', encoding='utf-8') as path_file:
            self.data = str(path_file.read()).split('\n')

        for i in self.data:
            if i:
                label = QLabel()
                label.setStyleSheet('font: 20px; background-color: grey;')
                label.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ActionsContextMenu)
                delete_action = QAction('Delete', self)
                delete_action.triggered.connect(lambda ch, i=i, label=label: self.delete_foo(i, label))


                label.addAction(delete_action)
                label.setText(i)
                self.vbox.addWidget(label)

        self.vbox.addWidget(self.restart_button)

    def reverse_foo(self):
        a = self.data
        a.reverse()

        with open('path.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as path_file:
            a = '\n'.join(a)
            path_file.write(a)
        self.close()
        print(1)
        self.__init__()
        print(2)

    def delete_foo(self, i, label):
        with open('path.txt', encoding='utf-8') as path_file:
            data = path_file.read()
            data = data.replace(i, '')
            data = data.split('\n')
            d = []
            for i in data:
                if i:
                    d.append(i)
            data = '\n'.join(d)

            with open('path.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output:
                output.write(data)
                label.deleteLater()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**path.txt**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Попытка внедрить способ из ответа. Крашится с ошибкой: 
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hide'` 
на строке `widget.hide()`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QAction, QLabel, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea


class DataManagerWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox.addStretch(1)
        self.vbox.setSpacing(15)

        self.button = QPushButton('restart')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.new_page)

        self.vbox.addWidget(self.button)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.page_init())


    def page_init(self):
        page_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(page_widget)

        self.main_box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.scrollarea = QScrollArea()
        self.area = QWidget()
        self.labels_box = QVBoxLayout()


        self.label = QLabel('0')


        self.labels_box.addWidget(self.label)
        self.area.setLayout(self.labels_box)
        self.scrollarea.setWidget(self.area)
        self.main_box.addWidget(self.scrollarea)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.main_box)


        return page_widget

    def new_page(self):
        widget = self.vbox.takeAt(0).widget()
        widget.hide()
        w = self.page_init()
        self.vbox.insertWidget(0, w)
        w.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = DataManagerWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: удаляете всех потомков в главном окне и заполняете снова. зачем окно закрывать-открывать?

Comment: Можно пример кода, какие методы использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Не получается внедрить в мою систему виджетов, добавил минимально воспроизводимый код и ошибку в тело вопроса.

Странно получается, вы задаете вопрос, получаете ответ. Потом приводите совсем другой пример и говорите, что у вас в нем что-то не получается. Я попробую решить вашу проблему совершенно другого вопроса.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QAction, QLabel, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea


class DataManagerWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox.addStretch(1)
        self.vbox.setSpacing(15)

        self.button = QPushButton('restart')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.new_page)

        self.num = 0                                             # +++

        self.vbox.addWidget(self.page_init())                    # +++
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.button)
#        self.vbox.addWidget(self.page_init())

    def page_init(self):
        page_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(page_widget)

        self.main_box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.scrollarea = QScrollArea()
        self.area = QWidget()
        self.labels_box = QVBoxLayout()

        self.label = QLabel(f' {self.num}')
        self.num += 1                                             # +++

        self.labels_box.addWidget(self.label)
        self.area.setLayout(self.labels_box)
        self.scrollarea.setWidget(self.area)
        self.main_box.addWidget(self.scrollarea)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.main_box)

        return page_widget

    def new_page(self):
        widget = self.vbox.takeAt(1).widget()                     # takeAt(1)
        widget.hide()
        w = self.page_init()
        self.vbox.insertWidget(1, w)                              # (1, w) 
        w.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = DataManagerWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прошу прощения, не думал, что наличие в лэйауте ещё каких-то виджетов так повлияет на ситуацию. Так то корень прежний. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @type49 мне кажется, что мой первый ответ как минимум оказался полезным для вас, т.к. вы применяли методы, которые я сконструировал в дальнейших своих примерах.

Comment: Верно. И я его плюсанул, два ответа нельзя ведь отметить решениями. Но в таком случае на будущее - в таких случаях создавать новый вопрос(если, конечно, самому не получится разобраться)?

Comment: @type49 новый пример - новый вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()

        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.restart_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Reverse')

        self.restart_button.clicked.connect(self.reverse_foo)

        with open('path.txt', encoding='utf-8') as path_file:
            self.data = str(path_file.read()).split('\n')

        self.vbox.addWidget(self.new_data())                                # + self.new_data()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.restart_button)

    def new_data(self):                                                     # +++
        page_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()                                
        page_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(page_widget)

        for i in self.data:
            if i:
                label = QLabel()
                label.setStyleSheet('font: 20px; background-color: grey;')
                label.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ActionsContextMenu)
                delete_action = QAction('Delete', self)
                delete_action.triggered.connect(lambda ch, i=i, label=label: self.delete_foo(i, label))
                label.addAction(delete_action)
                label.setText(i)
                page_layout.addWidget(label)
        return  page_widget       

    def new_page(self):                                                     # +++
        widget = self.vbox.takeAt(0).widget()
        widget.hide() 
        w = self.new_data()
        self.vbox.insertWidget(0, w)  
        w.show() 

    def reverse_foo(self):
        a = self.data
        a.reverse()
        with open('path.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as path_file:
            _a = '\n'.join(a)                                              # _a
            path_file.write(_a)                                            # _a

        self.data = a                                                      # +++ 
        self.new_page()                                                    # +++

    def delete_foo(self, i, label):
        with open('path.txt', encoding='utf-8') as path_file:
            data = path_file.read()
            data = data.replace(i, '')
            data = data.split('\n')
            d = []
            for i in data:
                if i:
                    d.append(i)
            data = '\n'.join(d)

            with open('path.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output:
                output.write(data)
#                label.deleteLater()                                        # ---
            self.data = d                                                   # +++
            self.new_page()                                                 # +++


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**path.txt**

```
D:/_Qt/__Qt/text_files/gif.gif
D:/_Qt/__Qt/text_files/loading.gif
D:/_Qt/__Qt/text_files/loading2.gif
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @type49 мой ответ решает ваш вопрос?

Comment: Не получается внедрить в мою систему виджетов, добавил минимально воспроизводимый код и ошибку в тело вопроса.